# ionic html data binding from database

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i have this html in my database.

```
<p>my data here. <b>bold a bit</b></p>
```

the database from factory like this

```
.factory('DataSingle', function($http, $q){
  var sContent = function(idc){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('http://mydomainrestserver/'+idc)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
     deferred.resolve(data);
    });
     return deferred.promise;
  }
 return { sContent : sContent }
})
```

this is my controller

```
.controller('SingleCtrl', function($scope, $http, DataSingle, $stateParams){
 var single_id = $stateParams.ids;
 DataSingle.sContent(single_id).then(

 function(single){
  $scope.singledata = single;
   }
})
```

singe the data is from database. it render as text instead of rendering it with paragraph and bold text.

what i get is just plain test from the view

```
Title: Single page
Data: <p>my data here. <b>bold a bit</b></p>
```

the data is successfully received but not rendered properly on my device. the question is, how to render the html from the result of query to ionic content view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in factory

```
$scope.singledata = $sce.trustAsHtml(single);
```

in html

```
<span ng-bind-html="singledata" class="htmlComment"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously all text content is escaped for security reasons unless you explicitely mark it as safe using the `$sce` service. So what you should do is:

```
$scope.singledata = $sce.trustAsHtml(single);
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce